# How to make many to one field in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

I want to make simple Django project based on book - author - publication

Here book has an author but author has multiple books.

Second I want relationship between book and publications, like publication has multiple books but book has one publication (if book published) or book has no publication (if book is not published) how can I make model for it ?

Where to use foreign key in this?

Comment: Now I can understand book-author relationship . What is the solution for book- publication relationship where relationship based on condition???

Comment: I somehow overlooked that, in that case you can make a `NULL`able `ForeignKey`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You a [**`ForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) for a *many-to-one* relation. Since your `Book` has *one* author, we thus specify a `ForeignKey` for the `Book` model:

```
from django.db import models

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    # some other fields
    # …

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        Author,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='books'
    )
```

The [**`related_name=…`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) specifies the name of the relation in reverse (so obtain all the `Book`s for a given `Author`), by default it is `modelname_set`, so here that would be `book_set`, but we can change it for example here to `books`.

You can then create an `Author` object, for example:

```
a = Author.objects.create(name='J R R Tolkien')
b1 = Book.objects.create(author=a, title='The Hobbit')
b2 = Book.objects.create(author=a, title='Lord of the Rings')
```

You then can access the `author` of a `Book`, for example `b1` as:

```
b1.author  # will return a
```

and we can obtain the books written by `a` with:

```
a.books.all()  # a queryset containing b1 and b2
```

For the publication, you can work with a `ForeignKey` again, but that `ForeignKey` can be `NULL`, we do that by specifying the [**`null=True`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null) parameter, and set [**`blank=True`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#blank), such that `ModelForm`s and `ModelAdmin`s will not see this as a required field:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        Author,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='books'
    )
    publication = models.ForeignKey(
        Publication,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='books',
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
```